# Oracle query to get Data from table inserted in last 10 mins

Tags: oracle, datetime

I have to get data from Oracle Table  in which I have one datefield called `lastupdatedDate` and I want to get only that rows back in which `lastupdatedDate` is in last 10 mins of `sysdate`

For example, if in my table I have `lastupdateDate` as  `05/20/09 4:20:44`  then I want this row back in my result if I run the query in between `05/20/09 4:20:44` and `05/20/09 4:30:44`, and not if if I run the query at `05/20/09 5:31:44`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
select *
from mytable
where lastupdatedDate > sysdate - interval '10' minute
```

Comment: While this yields the correct answer. I'd prefer the readability of @rob-van-wijk 's answer over this any day.

Comment: I think the same as @DrupadPanchal

Comment: @DrupadPanchal m missing lol icon

Answer (score 92):

Or slightly more readable:

```
select *
  from mytable
 where lastupdatedDate > sysdate - interval '10' minute
```

Comment: Dev friendly :)

Answer (score 14):

```
select sysdate - 10/(24*60) from dual;
```

See above example to get sysdate minus ten minutes, now just add to your query

Comment: I like this best.  It is clear what is being done and we don't have to remember the interval syntax.